# is just adding a tag a bad edit?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I recently made a one-tag edit on a question were I thought that the OP was asking/searching in the wrong direction. I made an comment to explain my line of thought. (basically, dojo's dijit system messes with the original html structure, the OP needs to use Javascript to access certain informations). The edit was here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16884926
(just the tag, the other lines were added later, I think)

the edit was rejected - which is ok for me, it was just a minor change on a not very well formulated question. But the reason given by two reviewer is

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

which makes me feel like it did something really, really bad. But I don't quite understand why exactly that edit was *this* evil.

Comment: it looks like a screenshot got deleted along the way.. OP may have added it just before you submitted yours and it looked like your edit removed it. [revision link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45415214/revisions)

Comment: Your edit deletes a link to an image. If that link was added before you had sent your suggestion doesn't matter for the review. That edit is not useful in the current state and was rightfully rejected.

Comment: It was a screenshot of *text*, specifically code, which shouldn't be in the question anyway. Referring to the edit as destructive feels like overkill (though I get that it should be replaced with text, not just deleted). That said, you shouldn't bother making edits to questions that can only be fixed by the OP anyway. Probably reduce the chances of this happening again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding a **proper** tag is a good edit. This might be crucial for someone to find and answer that question.

What isn't a good edit is adding proper tag and removing screenshot.

[image]

According to the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45415214/revisions), your edit applied right after the OP has edited his question. You were simply unlucky.

Comment: "Defacing the post" sounds like a serious allegation. Does that flag have the same penalties as when you have a spam or abusive flag levied against you?

Comment: That is correct. IMO, the reject reason should be different, but there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @SandPiper: No, that reject reason doesn't come with the same effects as a spam/offensive flag. For example, there's no -100 rep penalty (unlike with spam flags), and generally it isn't even raised to moderators. They do apparently feed [a little bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234954/3361440) into the spam blocking system, but I highly doubt one rejected edit with that reason will cause any major harm. So generally, spam and rude or abusive flags have much stiffer penalties than a single 'spam or vandalism' edit rejection.