# Why was my edit adding an appropriate tag to a question rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I am confused. Many times when I was asking a question here I was seeing this question edited just to retag it.

Nevertheless when I was trying to edit a question just to add an appropriate tag [the edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17354414). I was trying to add the tag [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) to a question asking what unit testing is: [How to actually Unit testing? And the most effective way with large code base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258106/how-to-actually-unit-testing-and-the-most-effective-way-with-large-code-base)

Could someone explain to me why was this edit rejected? I am confused even more by the fact that these answers in Meta seem to *encourage* this kind of edits I was trying to make:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251262 and
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354198

Comment: That question should just have been closed instead.

Comment: Because you were polishing a turd. As one of the answers you quote says: this kind of suggested edit is fine if tagging is **all that needs to be fixed** in the question. Clearly, that is not the case here.

Comment: I'm quite surprised that  language-agnostic has 2.4K followers.

Comment: I don't really have any problem with that the reviewers rejected your edit, but the problem I have with the way they reviewed it is that they didn't edit it themselves (Improve or Reject and Edit) to fix the formatting.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - Why edit a post that should be put on hold?

Comment: @BSMP Because it has answers so it won't be automatically deleted. If it wouldn't have had any answers, I would just have left it alone and let the Community user delete it as it is, but since it has answers and therefore might never be deleted, I thought it was better to edit it into shape.

Answer (score 16):

[The first answer you found, from hichris123](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251262) says:

> Yes, as long as this is the only thing that needs to be fixed.

Look again at [that question you edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258106/how-to-actually-unit-testing-and-the-most-effective-way-with-large-code-base) and tell me that the *only thing* that needed to be fixed there was the tag…

…yeah, I thought not. For starters, the code is not properly formatted. You could have, *at the very least*, fixed that, which is a *far* greater problem than it not having some tag. Then, there are grammar and capitalization problems that need to be fixed.

Aside from that, adding a [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag to a question like this is an *excessively minor* edit, and while we don't *prohibit* such edits, we certainly don't go out of our way to encourage them. Many reviewers will reject edits on this basis. The [unit-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) tag is sufficient to properly categorize that question. It doesn't need a [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag. In fact, I'm not even sure such a tag is appropriate. The question includes source code, and that's written in *some* language. It's more likely that the user actually wants to know about unit testing within the context of some specific language, they just didn't know that they should include a language tag. A better edit would have been to add that language tag.

Finally, a third problem with your edit is the one mentioned by Martijn in a comment on your question: you should avoid making trivial edits to obviously off-topic questions. That question was clearly too broad and unanswerable in our format—it asked *five* questions, which is way more than the expected one—so it needed to be closed, rather than edited. The only time you should edit a question like this is if you can fix the problems that would otherwise motivate its closure. Clearly, adding a tag of dubious value is not doing that, so the edit is not a good one.

Comment: Additionally one reviewer selected "This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains." - so presumably considered it a meta tag.